# Magento 2 : New Order Email Template CSS Not Working in Production Mode

Tags: magento2, css, email-templates, production-mode

I am facing issue in sales new order email template. I am working with my custom theme. Problem is there, new order email template **CSS working in developer mode** correctly but same template n**ot working on production** mode.

Can any one have resolve this issue or know more about it.

Thanks in advance